# What does (char*)-1 mean?

Tags: c, sbrk

I am wondering what does: `(char*)-1` mean and what does it evaluate to?
It is a return value from `sbrk()` in case of an error.

Comment: Odd: my `man sbrk` gives `void *sbrk(int incr);` as its declaration. Could you show and quote where you got that information from?

Comment: See https://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk for details

Comment: @Evert Yeah, I've found a few platform-dependent definitions online already, the [freeBSD one](https://github.com/lattera/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libstand/sbrk.c) uses `char *` and is probably fairly reliable.

Comment: (char*)-1 is an invalid pointer value. "On error, (void *) -1 is returned, and errno is set to ENOMEM" from the man page. memory management functions return `void *` not `char *`

Comment: (funny as I could not put -1 at the start of my comment, the system thought I wanted to express my downvote :))

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is just a way to return `-1` as a value from a function that normally returns a pointer - why they don't return `nullptr` instead is probably for legacy, but assigning it to a negative value is valid. It's not a dupe of the marked question, as that's specifically about assigning to a pointer address, whereas this is purely returning a value.

Comment: `brk` returns 0 when Ok, -1 when error. `sbrk` may mimic this error scheme.

Comment: This was closed with a **wrong** duplicate - now **this** is the correct one.

Comment: @VikasYadav: it is a pointer value that will not occur during normal operation.  Given a 2's complement integer, signed -1 has the same bit-pattern as the maximum value for the unsigned version of the same integer type.  So the implementers of this function knew that sbrk will not normally return the largest possible memory address.  Apparently they thought it more plausible that the break might be set at 0.

Comment: Code returning `(char*) -1` probably is pre-C89 code, stone-age old K&R C, from times where `void*` wasn't part of C yet.